# javascriptで外部ファイル化したjsファイルのグローバル変数の値を取得して処理を実行したい

Tags: javascript, html

javascriptで外部ファイル化したjsファイルのグローバル変数の値を取得して処理を実行したいのですが、undefinedになってしまいます。
すべてhtmlファイル上に記載したのと全く同じと思ったのですが違うのでしょうか？

その場合どうやって取得すればいいのですか？

html直書きだけではなく互いに別のファイルだった場合もありますが、
やはり分離するのは不可能なので一つのファイルにまとめるしかないのでしょうか？

Comment: ソースを見ないと何とも言えません。提示してください。

Comment: 基本的には可能なはずですが、両方外部ファイルにしているのであれば読み込み順などはどうなっていますか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11183158831